# An identity regarding symmetric difference of sets

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A,B$ be sets and define $A \triangle B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B
>  \setminus A )$. Show that $A \triangle B = (A \cup B) \setminus (A
>  \cap B )$.

#### Attempt:

Suppose $x \in A \triangle B$. By definition ,$ x \in (A \setminus B) \cup (B
 \setminus A )$. This is true $\mathbf{iff}$ $x \in (A \setminus B)$ OR $x \in (B \setminus A)$. This is equivalent to the following:

First, if $x \in A \setminus B$, then $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$, As $A \subset A \cup B$, and since $A \cap B \subset B$, we have $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \notin A \cap B$. By definition, we have $x \in (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$.

If $x \in B \setminus A$, we reach to similar conclusion.

Therefore, the result follows.

IS this a correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have successfully proved one direction of the equivalence. You now need to prove that if $x \in (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$, then $x \in A \triangle B$. Your reasoning probably reverses, but you haven't made that clear; in particular, you have started with the words "Suppose $x \in A \triangle B$", signalling that you intend to prove only one direction of the equivalence.